# Create object from text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have javascript text:

```
var textObject = '

        {
            news: [
                                                      { 
                "title":"aaa",
                "desc":"bbb"
                },                                      { 
                "title":"ccc",
                "desc":"ddd"
                }          ]
        }; 

'
```

but this is in text in my variable. If i have this in code html this working ok, but i get this data with ajax from PHP script.

So how can i convert/parse this text to object? If i have JSON then i can use JSON.parse(textObject); but this isn't json.

Comment: can you turn it into json? all that's missing is quotes around news and removing the semi-colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval is frowned upon for a lot of reasons, however it also has its benefits if used properly, it is used for a lot of template engines and a few other things but it will convert a string to an object.

```
var someString = '{obj: "with content"}';
eval( someString );
```

Here is a working example with your string: http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/CwzRh/

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` can result in serious performance degradation.

Since you can't do JSON, then use the `Function` constructor instead so that the evaling takes place in the global scope, and the browsers can still optimize the local code.

```
var result = new Function("return " + textObject.trim())();
```

---

You'll need to shim `.trim()` to support IE8. If the string is as you show with line breaks at the beginning, then the `.trim()` will be necessary.